# Windows reserved name "c​on" workaround / hack

Tags: java, windows, reserved-words

I understand that "con" is a reserved name in Windows, but is there a registry hack or something that will allow me to use it?

I'm on Windows 7 and trying to unzip a java project containing a file named "con.java". It fails every time.

From what I've learned, "con" is no longer used in Windows 7.

Comment: No, there's no registry hack. `con` has always been reserved, back to the MSDOS days, and has been carried forward essentially unchanged. it's the console, and that's it. same with `prn`, `com1`, etc...

Comment: Rename con.java inside the zip before unzipping? Btw, I think 7zip will rename the file automatically when you unzip.

Comment: I did that and it worked, but other classes trying to call it wouldn't be able to find it with its new name.

Comment: If you have the source of the dependants you can always refactor them.

Comment: What's with "con" not allowed in the post title? It's a semi-naughty word in french, but that shouldn't matter, should it?

Comment: @Kayaman: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334460/73070

Comment: @Kayaman It's done to direct questions in Spanish to the Spanish Stack Overflow. "con" is a Spanish word. This just happens to be a false positive.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Hey, how'd you do that ;) Ah, I see.

Comment: If you're not willing to modify the project to use a different class name, you'll need to build it on another OS, e.g., using a Linux VM.  You should still be able to *run* it on Windows, you'll just have to make sure that you put `con.class` into a .jar file.

Answer (score 2):

You can create files with reserved names by calling the Unicode version of CreateFile (CreateFileW) and prepending `\\?\` to the path. From Java you'd probably need JNI or similar to do that, or find a library that does that on your behalf.

However, keep in mind that creating files with names most other applications consider reserved will likely cause interoperability problems.

Comment: Will other files trying to access that renamed file be able to find it?

Comment: @gatzkerob: As noted, most applications simply pass the name to CreateFile without alterations and thus will not be able to open that file. They would see it, though.