# C# cannot open file named CON.DE.txt?

Tags: c#, .net

I encountered a strange issue in C# when i tried to open a txt file named CON.txt. I wanted to store yahoo finance data for the CON.DE symbol.

```
using System.IO;

namespace Test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            File.Open("CON.DE.txt", FileMode.Create);
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio throws an exception and says:

> FileStream will not open Win32 devices such as disk partitions and
>   tape drives. Avoid use of "\.\" in the path.

Is this a bug in .NET Framework or Win32? Is there a way around this?

Comment: `CON` is a reserved word in Windows file names (as in `copy CON`), as are `PRN` (`copy readme.txt > PRN`) and `COM`. I'd suspect the lack of letters following `COM` is triggering that status.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows and renaming folders, the 'con' issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448438/windows-and-renaming-folders-the-con-issue)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows reserved name "c​on" workaround / hack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475219/windows-reserved-name-con-workaround-hack)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that `CON` is a keyword reserved by Windows, harking back to the days of MS-DOS (but remaining reserved to this day).

One solution would be to replace the full stop between 'CON' and 'DE' with another character (e.g. `CON-DE.txt` or equivalent).

See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/74496/ms-dos-device-driver-names-cannot-be-used-as-file-names for a complete list of reserved MS-DOS device driver names.

Comment: Repro'd in Windows Explorer on Windows 10. Very nice catch!